# Unresolved refrence 'rasa_nlu' on PyCharm

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I am working on rasa project on PyCharm IDE and Mac OSX, and I am trying to create custom component class which is:

```
from rasa_nlu.components import Component
from rasa.nlu import utils
from rasa.nlu.model import Metadata
import nltk
import os
from profanity_filter import ProfanityFilter


class ProfanityAnalyzer(Component):

    name="profanity_analyzer"
    provides = []
    requries = ["entities"]
    deafults = {}
    language_list = ["en"]

    def __init__(self, component_config=None):
        super(ProfanityAnalyzer, self).__init__(component_config)

    def train(self, training_data, cfg, **kwargs):
        """Load the sentiment polarity labels from the text
           file, retrieve training tokens and after formatting
           data train the classifier."""

    def convert_to_rasa(self, value, confidence):
         entity = {"value":value,
                 "confidence":confidence,
                 "entity":"profane_word",
                 "extractor":"profanity_extractor"}

        return entity

    def process(self, message, **kwargs):
        pf=ProfanityFilter()
        text=message.text

        if pf.is_profane(text):
            tokens=text.split(" ")
            for token in tokens:
                if pf.is_profane(token):
                    value=token
                    confidence=100

        entity = self.convert_to_rasa(value,confidence)

        message.set("entities",[entity],add_to_output=True)

    def persist(self, file_name, model_dir):
        """Persist this model into the passed directory."""
```

it shows this error that all the imports except os, nltk could not be resolved!
[image]

and I tried to install the rasa nlu by the terminal by the following command:

```
pip install rasa_nlu
```

and it gives this error:

```
Collecting rasa_nlu
  Using cached rasa_nlu-0.15.1-py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3~=1.9 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (1.16.47)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm~=4.19 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests~=2.20 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.47 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (1.19.47)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.47->boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.47->boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (2.8.1)
Collecting cloudpickle~=0.6.1
  Using cached cloudpickle-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting coloredlogs~=10.0
  Using cached coloredlogs-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: humanfriendly>=4.7 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from coloredlogs~=10.0->rasa_nlu) (9.1)
Collecting future~=0.17.1
  Using cached future-0.17.1.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting gevent~=1.3
  Using cached gevent-1.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting greenlet>=0.4.14
  Using cached greenlet-0.4.17.tar.gz (61 kB)
Collecting jsonschema~=2.6
  Using cached jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting klein~=17.10
  Using cached klein-17.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from klein~=17.10->rasa_nlu) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from klein~=17.10->rasa_nlu) (1.15.0)
Collecting matplotlib~=2.2
  Using cached matplotlib-2.2.5.tar.gz (36.7 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/zahraaal-nemer/opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-install-w584fd2l/matplotlib_052328d9a48d4df5b2eccca54a9fc129/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-install-w584fd2l/matplotlib_052328d9a48d4df5b2eccca54a9fc129/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-t9qjhxas
         cwd: /private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-install-w584fd2l/matplotlib_052328d9a48d4df5b2eccca54a9fc129/
    Complete output (106 lines):
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.5]
                    python: yes [3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02)  [Clang
                            10.0.0 ]]
                  platform: yes [darwin]
    
    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.18.5]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                            be found.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
    
    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
    
    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]
    
    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no
    
    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]
    
    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How may I solve this error?

Comment: run code and see error message. And show full error message in question. Maybe these references are not problem and you shouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Are both rasa_nlu and profanity_filter installed?

Take a look at PyCharm settings. Browse to *Project settings* -> *Python Interpreter*. A list of all installed external packages is displayed. Are they present?

Comment: no they are not, and I want to install it as any package inside PyCharm, but no result when I am searching

Comment: Install them outside PyCharm with the pip utility.  Take a look at the official documentation from google for each package.

Comment: I have done that in the terminal and still it could not be installed, I added the details in the main supcext content